# What is the max value for page_size in Firestore RPC API?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I'm implementing a gRPC client for the Firestore API.

I'm calling `Firestore.ListCollectionIds` with a `page_size` of 1000 (since the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#google.firestore.v1.ListCollectionIdsResponse) mention that this field is an int32) but I only get 300 results back.

Could anybody officially confirm that?

Sample code:

```
request = V1.ListDocumentsRequest.new(
  parent: "projects/abc-123/databases/(default)/documents",
  page_size: 1000,
  collection_id: "something"
)
```

I do get the correct pagination when I use a value less than 300.

Comment: From a quick scan of some code it seems that 300 is the **default** page size. Can you edit your question to show how you pass the page size? Also: if you pass a value < 300, does it actually limit the results to that number?

Comment: Interesting. I couldn't find a maximum value anywhere, so hopefully somebody else can confirm/find a good source.

Comment: From the return do you have a `next_page_token` ? could be 300 is the number of result per page.
Also if from the result there are sub-documents, you will have to have `show_missing` set to `True`

Comment: @RyanJoseph I have 30000 records which I ideally would like to fetch in as big chunks as I can. But I get 300 per page which causes me to loop over all the pages (using the `next_page_token` in order to receive everything)